# Combining Multiple JSON arrays returned by Facebook Graph

Tags: php, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've tried searching for how to merge arrays, maybe I have a Facebook specific issue. I'm trying to merge arrays which contain data about events the specific people are going to. Here is my PHP so far:

```
    //Define FQL Query
$fql = "SELECT uid,education,name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid2=me())";
$param = array(
                'method'    => 'fql.query',
                'query'     => $fql,
                'callback'  => '');
//Execute Query
$fqlres = $facebook->api($param);
//Start Blank Array
$friend_events_array = '';
//Loop through results and display events of students of a particular college
foreach($fqlres as $friend){
    if($friend['education'] == ''){
        //If friend does not have an education_history array display Nothing
    }
    else {
        foreach($friend["education"] as $friendEd) {
            //If friend is a college student
            if($friendEd["type"] == "College") {
                $collegeinfo = $friendEd;
                $schoolinfo_friend = $collegeinfo['school'];
                    //If the name of the friend's college is the same as the user's college.
                    if ($schoolinfo_friend['name'] == $schoolinfo_user['name']){
                        echo $friend['name'].": ".$schoolinfo_friend['name'];
                        echo "<br>";
                        //Query Graph for Events
                        $friend_events = $facebook->api($friend['uid']."/events");
                        //Display Events
                        print_r($friend_events);
                        //Merge Arrays
                        $friend_events_array_new = array_merge($friend_events, $friend_events_array);
                        //Rename Array for Looping
                        $friend_events_array = $friend_events_array_new;
                    }

            }

        } 

    }
}
```

First, I get a list of all the user's friends (I have all the necessary permissions like education_history, friends_events, and user_education_history. I first run through the list and get all the users that have an education array in their user object. Then I go into each education array and see if they are a college student, and then I check to see if their college matches the user's college. If that all checks out then I make an API call to the graph to get and Array of their events. Each event array returns successfully but I would like to know if it is possible to then try and merge each new Event Array in the Loop to a main event array that would grow with each friend that is processed.

Thoughts?

Also, each individual event array looks like this:

```
Array ( [data] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => WU Alumni Meet [start_time] => 2011-10-21T17:00:00 [end_time] => 2011-10-23T13:00:00 [location] => Athletic Complex [id] => 197913876920275 [rsvp_status] => attending ) ) [paging] => Array ( [previous] => https://graph.facebook.com/3100772/events?limit=25&since=1319216400 [next] => https://graph.facebook.com/3100772/events?limit=25&until=1319216400 ) )
```

Does this matter?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding this correctly, then what you are trying to do is create a combined list of all the user's friend's unique events.

In your example, it looks like $friend_events_array is your array of all the events from all the user's friends. If that's the case, then I believe you are already creating an array that is expanding. You should take a look at the [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) function in PHP though, to make your array's values unique.

```
  print_r($friend_events);
  //Merge Arrays
  $friend_events_array_new = array_merge($friend_events, $friend_events_array);
  //Rename Array for Looping
  $friend_events_array = $friend_events_array_new;
  $friend_events_array = array_unique($friend_events_array);
```

Comment: the `$friend_events_array` is empty though when after I loop through all the users and `echo $friend_events_array`